# Adding progress bar when fetching data using resolver in new tab

Tags: angular

In our application, there is a table, onclick of details button in table row, new tab will be opened,I am using resolver to fetch the data before loading the tab. Since data fetch is taking time, I am seeing blank screen for around 5 to 10s. Is it possible to add a progress bar before application loads UI?

I already have progress bar that will be loaded whenever there is an http intercept happens. Since UI is not loaded for this scenario, loader is not coming up

Since resolver are added, its taking time to fetch data, so until data is fetched i am seeing blank screen. SO during that data fetching time i want to show a progress bar.How will i do that???

```
  {
        path: 'details',
        resolve: {
          details: DeviceResolverService,
        },
        component: DetailsComponent,
      },
```

This route is opened in new tab.

If so how will i show progress bar when UI is not loaded, while data is fetching?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blockUI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-block-ui) to solve your problem :

`npm i ng-block-ui`

Wrap your tab in the `blockUI`

```
<div *blockUI="'fetch-data-block-ui'">
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then in your resolver service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductResolverService implements Resolve<any>  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  @BlockUI('fetch-data-block-ui') blockUIList: NgBlockUI;

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    // start loading 
    this.blockUIList.start();

    return this.http.get('ULR').pipe(
      map((response) => {
        // after getting the result here, you have to stop the loading 
        this.blockUIList.stop()
        return response;
      }),
      catchError((err, caught) => {
        this.blockUIList.stop()
        return of(null)
      })
    )


  }
}
```

do not forget to import BlockUIModule in your module

```
  imports: [
   ...
    BlockUIModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```